# Whatsapp doesn't detect the mime type of file sent through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

I have implemented the export/share feature in my app and the file being exported to / shared between other apps is a custom mime type of **.tmly** that I created. When I use the code below to share the file Uri, WhatsApp detects the file as a **.bin** and not a **.tmly** file extension, therefore, when I click on the file sent to Whatsapp, it doesn't show my app in the list that opens a **.bin** file. Actually, when I send the file from another app, Whatsapp detects it as a **.tmly** file and whenever I click on the file sent to Whatsapp, my app shows in the **Android Sharesheet** or chooser as one of the apps that can open up the file. Code that performs the action below:

```
// opens up chooser, used to send send the Uri of the exported file
     btn_share.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        if (file.exists()) {
           String shareTextSubject = getString(R.string.share_text_subject_1);

           shareIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/tmly");
           shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareTextSubject);
           shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareTextSubject);
           shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
           shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_text_subject_2)));
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_share_subject_text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```

I will also add the part in my **Manifest.xml** file that declares the activity to open up the file.

```
   <activity
         android:name=".exports.ImportResultsActivity"
         android:exported="true"
         android:priority="1"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.SlideVertical_recipient">
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tmly" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
         </intent-filter>

         <!--  Work-around so that TimeLY is able to import data from Whatsapp and MIUI File manager -->

         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text" />
            <data
               android:mimeType="application/pdf"
               android:scheme="file" />
            <data
               android:mimeType="application/pdf"
               android:scheme="content" />

         </intent-filter>

      </activity>
```

Comment: Did you find any soloution?

Comment: I haven't found a solution. I just made my app to also open PDFs (which Whatsapp detects) as a way to fix it for now